# IIS crashes at startup - inetinfo.exe - memory could not be read

Tags: windows-xp, iis

Running

- Windows XP SP3
- IIS 5.1

I get this error when I boot my PC.

`Application popup: inetinfo.exe - Application Error : The instruction at "0x5aa3b134" referenced memory at "0x00000004". The memory could not be "read".`

when I try to navigate to a http://localhost/ I get this error

`Faulting application inetinfo.exe, version 5.1.2600.5512, faulting module w3svc.dll, version 5.1.2600.5512, fault address 0x0001b134.`

It also kills and restarts the IIS Admin and World Wide Web Publishing services.

Any ideas what the problem could be or how to further diagnose?

Answer (score 1):

Turn off IMON in NOD32 Anivirus.

Answer (score 0):

Could be bad RAM.  If you've got some RAM testing software, run that.  Could also be corrupt software.  If possible, try reformatting and reinstalling everything.